# Fabricjs - edit an element of a group

Tags: fabricjs

I'm using loadSVGfromURL to import an SVG in my canvas. I would like to change the color of a path in my SVG, using a colorpicker.

So far I came up with this :

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(site_url,(objects,options) => {

  objects.find(i => i.id === 'colored1').set({fill: color)}`})
  const loadedObjects = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options)
  loadedObjects.scaleToWidth(this.canvas.getWidth())
  this.canvas.add(loadedObjects)
  this.canvas.renderAll();

});
```

The problem is, this forces me to reload all elements of my SVG. Is there a way to edit one of my objets attributes after using groupSVGelements ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes use third parameter reviveropt for update specific object property

```
fabric.loadSVGFromURL(site_url, (objects, options) => {
  const loadedObjects = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options)
  loadedObjects.scaleToWidth(this.canvas.getWidth())
  this.canvas.add(loadedObjects)
  this.canvas.renderAll();
}, function(object) {
  if (object.id === "colored1") {
    object.set({
      fill: color
    });
  }
});
```